# Bulk edit of EXIF data for jpeg images uploaded in the media library?

Tags: images, uploads, media, media-library

Although there's a number of [plugins](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=exif) that display EXIF data in your posts or remove EXIF data altogether to save space, I couldn't find a solution to manually edit EXIF data for whole bunches of images (eg. remove some data, replace other, selectively edit some EXIF fields, etc.).

Is there any plugin to do this within the WP dashboard? Otherwise can you recommend any external non-WordPress tool that can log into (S)FTP fetch my files in upoads and can do the same task? The thing is it should work also for scaled media (thumbnails), each image could have more than one size - edits should apply for any of these while editing a single image.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but for the record, there is a command line ExifTool

Win & Mac versions found here: http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

exiftool mypic.jpg -title="A new title"

Would change the title but there are hundreds of other tags you can change.